# How to insert specific data to consecutive cells in a column

Tags: excel, vba, text, insert

Im a total newb here and trying to accomplish what i thought was a simple task with Excel.

What i need to do is insert the text "Rakennus" to the 1st available cell, the time and date to the next 2 cells. I already have a macro that copies data from sheet 1 to sheet 2. This new data needs to be inserted in to sheet 2, column A in a consecutive manner.

```
  Application.Sheets("Taul2").Select.LastRow .Range("A" & Rows.Count) = "Rakennus".End(x1up).Row + 1
  Application.Sheets("Taul2").Select.LastRow .Range("A" & Rows.Count) = Now.End(x1up).Row + 2
  Application.Sheets("Taul2").Select.LastRow .Range("A" & Rows.Count) = Date.End(x1up).Row + 3
```

My skills are very limited and this is what i've collected and modified, just can't get it to work

Any kind of insight appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After locating the last used row with `.End(xlUp)`, use `.Offset(1, 0)` to move down 1 row to insert the text value. When that is done, use a similar technique to locate that cell and `.Offset(0, 1)` to the right for the date and `.Offset(0, 2)` for the time.

```
With Sheets("Taul2")
    .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "Rakennus"
    .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = Date
    .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = Time
End With
```

If the three values were to be vertically oriented, then you would just continue the original offset.

```
With Sheets("Taul2")
    .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "Rakennus"
    .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Date
    .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Time
End With
```

Using `.Resize(3, 1)` together with `.Transpose(...)` on an array of the three values would get the job done in a single code line.

```
With Sheets("Taul2")
    .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(3, 1) = Application.Transpose(Array("Rakennus", Date, Time))
End With
```

Comment: This is very insightful, thank yoU!. Right now it adds the information into the row, when i would like it to follow rather the column "A" downwards.

Comment: @Jesse - The offset command is simply `.Offset(<number of rows>, <number of columns>)`. If you wanted the three values stacked vertically, just use `.Offset(1, 0)` for each of them.